# Typescript: cast to another similar type

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm using TS to build a node express API. I distinguish between `model`and `viewmodel` classes. A `Post` model class can have several viewmodel representations.

But how do I cast from model to a viewmodel class? I can make a method that creates new viewmodel objects. But is it possible to just cast to another type?

**Example**

*Post.ts*

```
export interface IPost {
    id: number;
    author: string;
    heading: string;
    body: string;
}

/**
 * Class to model a blog post
 */
export class Post implements IPost {

    public id: number;
    public author: string;
    public heading: string;
    public body: string;

    constructor(id: number, author: string, heading: string, body: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.heading = heading;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

*PostVM.ts*

```
export interface IPostVM {
    id: number;
    author: string;
    text?: string;
}

/**
 * Class to model a blog post
 */
export class PostVM implements IPostVM {

    public id: number;
    public author: string;
    public text?: string;

    constructor(id: number, author: string, body: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.text = body;
    }
}
```

*App.ts*

```
// This is NOT working:
const post: IPost = this.dao.getPostById(id);
const postVM: IPostVM = post as PostVM;
```

Result:

```
{
    "author": "Ole",
    "body": "Dette er en test på body tekst.",
    "heading": "Overskrift 1",
    "id": 1
}
```

Should be:

```
{
    "id": 1
    "author": "Ole",
    "text": "Overskrift 1",
}
```

Comment: The two types are not compatible. What would you expect the program to do in a cast from `Post` to `PostVM`?

Comment: Type assertions never affect runtime behavior. Also, how do you expect the computer to know that `heading` should become `text` ?

Comment: So only way is to make factory method that creates PostVMs?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just "cast" it since, as a comment said there's no way to know how you want the classes converted unless you write it yourself.

Best you can do is likely, as you said, write a function for the class:

```
export class Post implements IPost {
    <...>

    toPostVM() {
        return new PostVM(this.id, this.author, this.body);
    }
}
```

So then in your App.ts you can do:

```
const postVM: IPostVM = post.toPostVM();
```